# Getting Multi Rows in Database and transferring it in a multiline textbox in VB.net WinForms

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, textbox

Here in my code, i have a database which has table of my applicants. As you will see in the code below, i want to get the number of rows from my command text and transfer it to the string "abc"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myr.Close()
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = "SELECT Count(Cellphone) FROM tbl_applicant where Gender='Female';"
    myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
    Dim abc As String
    If myr.Read Then
        abc = myr(0)
    End If
    myr.Close()
```

On the code Below i used the abc as the number of data i must acquire. Then i used the new query to get the values i wanted to and transfer them to a String Array, as you can see I Redim the universal variable Numb to abc to have its array boundery.

```
    mycom.CommandText = "SELECT Cellphone FROM tbl_applicant where Gender='Female';"
    myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
    ReDim Numb(abc)
    If myr.Read Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To abc.ToString - 1
            LOT = myr(0).ToString
            LOT = LOT + (myr(i).ToString + ",") <- this is where i get the error it says that index is our of range.
            Numb = LOT.Split(",")
        Next
    End If
```

In this code below, i want the values of Variable Numb() to be transferred to a multiline textbox

```
    Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Numb.Length - 2
        ' This will convert the number to a string, add it to the stringbuilder
        ' and then append a newline to the text buffer
        sbText.AppendLine(Numb(i))
    Next i
    ' Now move the buffer into the control
    TextBox1.Text = sbText.ToString()

End Sub
```

The end value i must see in the textbox should be like

11111111111

11111111112

11111111113

11111111114

and so forth, please try to understand the numbers i am referring it to real phone numbers. Any help with the problem or solution maybe.. Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `List<string>` instead of resizing an array? `List` resizes itself and you can simply read all the phone numbers into the `List` if you need to or just execute the reader and populate the textbox from that - Further looking at your code I think a lot of it can be removed and made much simpler

Comment: change: LOT = LOT + (myr(i).ToString + ",") with:  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & myr(0) & Environment.NewLine

Comment: Or better look at Ric answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to first query the db to get the count of records before then going back to the db to get the phonenumbers, you could just do this:

```
mycom.CommandText = "SELECT Cellphone FROM tbl_applicant where Gender='Female';"
myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
While myr.Read()
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & myr(0) & Environment.NewLine
End While
```

No need for `array`'s or `List`'s

While this is just a rough guide and an attempt at understanding your issue, try the code and see if it works for you.